# Is it possible to redirect specific messages to a recipient in Postfix?

Tags: queue, postfix-mta

Currently I have plenty of emails in my postfix "hold" queue. These are all emails returned when sending newsletters. (Messages due to mailbox full, invalid email, and so on).

The problem is that these email came back based on different newsletter accounts, with different email lists.

What I would like to do is the following :

For each message in the hold queue, define a rewrite to a specific recipient, for example newsletter1-return@ourdomain.org or newsletter2-return@ourdomain.org.

For example I know that message F4230148D6B5 should go to newsletter1-return@ourdomain.org, message F422314D10C3 should go to newsletter8-return@ourdomain.org, and so on...

Do you know if there is some way to do that in postfix ?

Any advice or idea will be appreciated :-)

Thanks a lot !

P. S. Sorry if this question is rather original or out of normal usage !

Answer (score 1):

I'm handling your problem differently. I'm parsing mail.log daily via bash script, getting permanent and temporary failures from it, then I unsubscribe them from newsletters depending on my policy.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, this is interesting too... But don't you miss some other failures that only come back later to postmaster ?

Comment: for emails that service reports ok then fails?